# Target a window when verifing from an email link

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a sign up page on my site. After entering your info, the site sends out an email to verify the user. From that email link:

**I wonder how I can target the previously opened window to my site?**
(Which would currently say: Thank You for signing up, please check your email for a validation token)

Placed in the body tag of the site is:

```
<body onload="window.name='thesite';">
```

Have tried to send an `<a>` tag with a target="thesite" from the email using PHP's mail() function with Content-type: text/html, but the target won't take.

```
<body><html>    
<a href="http://www.demo.com/index.php?token=123456789" target="thesite">Verify</a>
</body></html>
```

Seems like it would, but it just opens a new window.

Comment: You want my mail application to open a specific window in my browser? I doubt it even _can_. AFAIK this is not possible, except for maybe very specific email-client / browser combo's.

Comment: BTW, if you can state your purpose and tell us what you are trying to achieve, I'm sure we can try and point out a solution that is within the realm of possibility.

Comment: Purpose: Target a window when verifying from an email

Comment: Trying to achieve: Target the previously opened window to my site

Comment: How many people who cant understand what they are reading: At least one!

Answer (score 1):

It rather annoying that there is no one-step simple solution (you cannot target the opened window to my knowledge), here is a solution I think will work:

- The 'click here to verify' page has a script checking a cookie every 200 milliseconds with something to the effect of setInterval("CheckVerified();", 200). Where CheckVerified() navigates to http://www.demo.com/index.php?token=-token_from_cookie- which has a body.focus() as an onload event.
- The link inside the email goes to a page with two onload functions to the effect of - SetCookie(name, -token from parameter from link in email-); window.close();

Basically, the link in the email opens a page which changes a cookie, then instantly closes. The original page showing a message like 'waiting for verification...' notices the changed cookie and responds by navigating to the actual PHP verification script. It is important the original verification page is opened in a window to start with (if it is a tab, its javascript will be frozen when it does not have focus) therefore the body.focus() is needed to bring it to the user's attention.

Although this method seems some what tedious, it avoids window cross scripting and other fun security issues.